# Какие запятые нужны и в связи с какими правилами?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение, и

*Узнайте кто ее запрашивал и почему вам отказывают кредитные организации.*

Answer (score 3):

Союз "и" в этом сложноподчиненном предложении соединяет между собой два простых придаточных предложения. Запятая перед "и" в этом случае не ставится.

*[Вы] Узнайте* — главное предложение (что? о чем?), оно отделяется запятой.

**Узнайте, кто ее запрашивал и почему вам отказывают кредитные организации.**

[Трудные случаи пунктуации. Запятая перед союзом «И»](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/315-zapyatayaperedsyuzomi.html)

Answer (score 3):

*Узнайте, кто ее запрашивал и почему вам отказывают кредитные организации.*

В этом предложении **общей частью** для двух придаточных предложений является главная часть - УЗНАЙТЕ.

В случае, когда главная часть является общей для придаточных предложений, запятая перед союзом И, соединяющим придаточные, не ставится.

Главное предложение отделяем запятой.